# Spring Ownership based access

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security

Please don't mark this as duplicate as provided solutions available contains security issues and do not cover all CRUD-cases!

I want to secure certain objects by comparing the stored `userId` of an object with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication`.

I am aware that I have to fetch the object before doing operations since this is the only way to get the `userId`.

I want to secure controller-methods like this one:

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/deliveryAddresses/{id}")
    fun getDeliveryAddressById(@PathVariable(value = "id") deliveryAddressId : Long): 
        ResponseEntity<BasicDeliveryAddress> {
            return deliveryAddressService.findById(deliveryAddressId)?.let { ResponseEntity.ok(it) } 
                ?: ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
    }
```

What is the best-practice approach to secure this object? I don't want to have multiple duplicate ownership-checks accross my code. Also please suggest where to add the check (Controller, Service, ... ?)

This is exactly what I want to avoid (pseudo-code):

```
fetchById(id) {
    val myObject = ...
    if(myObject.userId == authUser.userId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Please provide a clean solution for this problem.

### UPDATE - PART OF SOLUTION

I was not aware that I am able to directly get the object inside the method header by only passing the ID.

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/something/{id}")
fun getSomethingByID(@PathVariable(value = "id") something: Something): ResponseEntity<BasicDeliveryAddress> { ... }
```

With this additional information and the answer (accepted one) provided by @Ken Chan you should be able to easily implement the ownership based security!

Comment: Use @PostFilter ot the object.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-prefilter-postfilter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@PreAuthorize` which allows you to define a SpEL which will be evaluated as boolean to see if a method is allow to be executed.

You have several options:

(1) Use SpEL to refer to bean method that perform the checking :

```
@PreAuthorize("@authzService.isAllowToDo(#deliveryAddressId)")
public ResponseEntity<BasicDeliveryAddress> getDeliveryAddressById(Long deliveryAddressId {

}


@Service
public class AuthzService{

    public boolean isAllowToDo(Long deliveryAddressId){
        //Do the checking here....
    }
}
```

(2) Use the built-in [`hasPermission`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize) expression  :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#deliveryAddressId, 'read')")
public ResponseEntity<BasicDeliveryAddress> getDeliveryAddressById(Long deliveryAddressId{

}
```

It requires to customise [`PermissionEvaluator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-permission-evaluator) to work. Same idea as (1) but it is a built-in solution.

(3) If the evaluation logic is simple and the method signature is
    allowed, you can directly expressed it using SpEL :

```
@PreAuthorize("#deliveryAddress.userId == authentication.userId")
public ResponseEntity<BasicDeliveryAddress> getDeliveryAddressById(BasicDeliveryAddress deliveryAddress){

}
```

`authentication` is one of the built-in expression to access the Authentication object in the `SecurityContextHolder` and I assume you have already customised it to include `userId`.

Comment: This would mean I need to fetch the `deliveryAddress` twice in the first soultion, right? For checking permissions and afterwards directly in `getDeliveryAddressById`.

3rd solution: This would mean I first need to fetch the `BasicDeliveryAddress` and afterwards pass it in the method? This is pretty confusing to me as this method is expected to do that. Or how is the 3rd solution expected to work since I am only passing the ID and not the whole object.

Comment: If you are using JPA  , and you query the object that you want to process by ID, the object will be cached in the JPA 1st level cache for the same transaction.  That mean in the 2nd time in the same transaction, it just return the object from the cache.

Comment: I can see in the mysql logs the query is executed twice, so it doens't seem like its caching.

Comment: you have to use entityManager.find(Foo.class, 1) to use the 1st level cache . Using not using JPQL . Using query cache may help if using JPQL to get the result